# How to find the distance attained by a sphere after being compressed by a spring?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

> A smooth sphere with negligible friction of $m=100\,g$ is released
>   from $A$. The spring compresses to $10\,cm$. As a result the sphere
>   reaches B, but at this point it is measured the velocity to be zero.
>   Given this conditions. Find the distance in meters between $A$ and
>   $B$. Assume: $K=600\,\frac{N}{m}$ and $g=10\,\frac{m}{s^2}$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{3 m}\\
2.&\textrm{4 m}\\
3.&\textrm{5 m}\\
4.&\textrm{6 m}\\
4.&\textrm{10 m}\\
\end{array}$

What I've attempted to do was to establish the conservation of mechanical energy as follows:

$E_p=E_g$

$mgh=\frac{1}{2}kx^2$

Now the problem arises from which length should be used in consideration here?.

What I did was:

$(0.1)(10)(x\sin 37^{\circ})=\frac{1}{2}(600)(10\times10^-2)^2$

Simplifying this expression I obtained:

$x=5\,m.$ Which corresponds to the answer. But I'm not very convinced of my method. Does it exist another way to do this problem?. In this case the height which I'm assuming if counted from point $A$ to point $B$ and not exactly from where the spring is compressed. But does it exist a justification for this?.

Why the compression of the spring is not expressed in the y direction as $10\cos 37^{\circ}$?. I've already attempted that but it did not work.

Can someone help me here please?.

Comment: The length of compression of a spring is always measured along the axis of the spring.

Comment: @YNK Can you please indicate exactly what do you mean by the axis of the spring?. Does it mean that the length should never be established as if the spring is put in a vertical position?.

Comment: The axis of the spring is the direction in which it is either compressed or elongated. A spring can be placed in any direction including vertical. If a spring is placed vertically, then its axis is vertical.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$$
\frac 12 K (\Delta x)^2 = (|AB|+\Delta x)m g\sin\theta 
$$